# Firebase Unity iOS notifications doesn't show badge counter on app icon

Tags: ios, firebase, unity-game-engine, apple-push-notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

I recently set up my notifications using Firebase. I'm sending, receiving notifications like intended. On Android, notification dots are working, showing up dots on app icon but on iOS red badge is not showing up on icon so no counter either. I badly want this functionality can anybody give clue about the problem? Is Firebase Unity iOS notifications are supposed to work like this? Thanks!

Comment: Can you share how you're sending these notifications? The displaying of a badge is handled at the OS level, so I don't think it has anything to do with Unity specifically.

Comment: I used default firebase console to send notifications. Now tried advanced options, there was badge option, enabled it, now badge is shown but there is another problem now. Badge is not disappearing)) Tired clearing notifications, opening program but no luck, still +1 stands on app icon

Comment: Aww I figured it out, I have to clear notifications from app manually :/ Thanks for help!

Answer (score 2):

I' didn't choose advanced notification and badge was disabled by default. That was the problem